# enable send button on rightclick and paste

Tags: javascript, click, event-listener

i have write a function to disable my send button in chat area while there is no invalid data input.

```
    _validateChatDraft: function() {
    var chat = this.input.value.trim();
    var isFileSelected = we.useNativeUpload ? this.uploadImageData : !!this.uploadInput.value;
    if (isFileSelected) {
      this.btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
      return;
    }
    if (chat === '') {
      this.btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      this.btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
  },
```

but right now my send button is disabled in paste event.

i have also used these 3 lines that seems 3th one doesn't work:

```
        this.input.addEventListener('keyup', this._validateChatDraft.bind(this));
    this.uploadInput.addEventListener('change', this._validateChatDraft.bind(this));
    this.input.addEventListener('paste', this._validateChatDraft.bind(this));
```

Comment: can you add a working jsfiddle or the html markup of your chat area?

Comment: i'm afraid i can't make it. :(

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste - looks like the `paste` event fires before any changes are made to the value, so at that point your value can still be empty. Is `change` also triggered after you paste?

Comment: i change the position of 'paste'  above 'change'.but still doesn't work

Comment: which html elements are `this.input` and `this.uploadInput` ?

Comment: [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/fsqobt1d/13/) a basic js example with an `input` and a `button` which detects both `keyup` and `paste` event and enables the button after you input "test"

Answer (score 2):

actually my problem is solved with  just changing 'keyup' to 'input' , that is more general and includes all cases

```
    this.input.addEventListener('input', this._validateChatDraft.bind(this));
```